# Can't install 82579V ethernet card on Debian

Tags: debian, ethernet, kernel-module

I just installed Debian 6.0.1 on a new machine today. It has a `Intel DH67CFB3 motherboard` and a built-in ethernet card which is the `Intel 82579V`. I googled around for a while trying to find how to install this ethernet card. This is what I have tried so far:

- During install, tried selecting the "82579 generic module", didn't work
- During install, tried selecting the "e1000 module", didn't work
- During install, tried selected the "e1000e module", didn't work
- After install ran insmod with path to e1000e module .ko-files, didn't work

I'm stuck at the moment and would appreciate some enlightenment!

Background info:

When I run ifconfig it only shows the loopback.
Interfaces files only contain config for loopback
When I run `lspci -v`, this is the info I get for the ethernet card:

```
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579V Gigabit Network Connection (rev 05)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 2000
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 10
Memory at fe500000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128k]
Memory at fe528000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4]
I/O ports at f080 [size=32]
Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 2
Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
Capabilities: [e0] PCI Advanced Features
```

I obviously most have missed something, or am I doomed to not being able to use this ethernet card?

Comment: When you ran insmod, did you use the *full* path to the ko files? And where did you obtain the ko files?

Comment: Also, what kernel are you using? And also post the output from `lspci -nnk`.

Comment: emb1995: Yes, I used the full path; "/lib/kernel/.../e1000e.ko", taken from ouput of "find / -name "e1000e". I'm not at the office right now, so I can't check. But I'll check in the morning!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Debian 6 (Squeeze) did not originally come with support for the Intel 82579V NIC, a blogger came up with [this guide](http://perfect-co.de/2011/04/intel-82579v-gigabit-ethernet-driver-for-debian-squeeze/). According to Intel's website, this e1000e driver should work, it's just that the driver version you have is old. I would suggest actually pulling the latest version [from here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/e1000/files/e1000e%20stable/), and building the modules on your machine so that you have the latest version module. The readme inside the folder has complete instructions.

All of this really occurred because of bad timing. [This forum thread](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/archive/index.php/t-257676.html) towards the bottom stated that:

> The patch for this device was added just as 2.6.35 was closed.
>   So you'll need a 2.6.36 kernel.